# Infinite Series for Arctan

Tags: calculus

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)
$$

Does anyone know how to determine if this infinite series diverges or converges and if it converges, what its value is?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange.  It is expected that you include with your question the attempt(s) you have made.  Please edit your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: FYI, a lot of these types of questions can be answered with wolfram alpha. It not only tells you whether it converges or not, but the test that can be used.

Comment: The other question I have is why is it off topic? I shouldn't have put it in the  calculus section? What section should I have put it in then?

Answer (score 2):

The series converges, because $\arctan x< x$, for $x>0$, so
$$
\arctan\frac{1}{k^2}< \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
and …

Comment: Would like to add that the approximate value is 1.424

Answer (score 1):

I found this sum , but I will not post here " because these margins are too small for this " :) . Instead, I'll tell you how I did, but know already that this will require plenty of algebraic calculations . here goes:
See that $arctg(x) = i/2*ln((i+x)/{(i-x)})$, so the Sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$ is equivalent to $i/2*ln(\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+1/({k^2*i})/(1-1/({k^2*i}))$;
Now, Use the trick of Euler to calculate the sum of the inverse of the squares http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/euler.pdf
 and see that $sin{x}/x=\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-x^2/(\pi^2*k^2))$, so $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = i/2*ln({sin{(\pi*(e^{\pi*i/4}))}/sin{(\pi*e^{-\pi*i/4}})*e^{-\pi*i/2}})$

---

$sin{(\pi*(e^{\pi*i/4}))}/sin{(\pi*e^{-\pi*i/4}})*e^{-\pi*i/2} = 0.95763...-i*(0.28797...)$ (let's call this $a$)
so, $i/2*ln(a) = 1.4247417784299...$

Comment: For completeness, write out the final answer for the sum.